# Splash screen in Cocos Sharp app

Tags: c#, android, mono

I'm making a game in Cocos Sharp. When it is launched, black screen appears. I wanna do some splash screen instead. I try the way described [there](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/). So my splash screen activity class code is:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]            
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

Main activity:

```
[Activity (Label = "MainActivity")]
public class MainActivity : AndroidGameActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        var application = new CCApplication();
        application.ApplicationDelegate = new MyApp.AppDelegate();
        SetContentView(application.AndroidContentView);
        application.StartGame();
    }
}
```

And my theme style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

But when I launch the app, it just says "Unfortunately, app has stopped.". So I'm asking what my problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to set your MainActivity as the startup activity as usual, and change the theme of MainActivity to "@style/Theme.Splash" instead.